# Expressjs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I know there are other questions about this error, but none of them helped me. Everything was working fine untill I decided to add consign and change my directories structure.

I tried changing the orders my route is being loaded, but did not work

This is server.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign'); 
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const porta = 3000;

const app = express();
const pathFront = '../app/front/';

//app.use(require('../app/routes/'));


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, pathFront + 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, pathFront + 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(require('../app/routes/')); // still not working

// Tried to change the include order, did not work
consign()
    .include('./app/routes')
    .then('./config/db.js')
    .then('./app/back/api/models')
    .then('./app/back/api/controllers')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

This is route index:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'API' });
});

/* ENDPOINTS*/
/* 
  /languages -- all
  /language?idLanguage
  /language?name=
  /languages?idCategory
  /language?name=
  /categories
  //
*/

module.exports = router;
```

This is folder structure:

[image]

And running npm start:

[image: e]

Comment: you are mixing old express syntax with new express syntax. your error might go away if you switch to the new express syntax for declaring routes, and upgrading all your packages to their express 4.x versions, and upgrade express its self to 4.x if it isn't already. the way you are routing in your index file looks like express 2.x syntax. also your routes need to come after your middleware, not before

Comment: ok... thank you, i'm going to do that

Comment: how do I know what package version corresponds to determined express version?

Comment: they probably all depend on express 3/4 by now, so just install the latest versions and save that in your package.json. `npm install --save <all your packages here>` should update the old ones

Comment: i changed the way the route was being called and run npm install as you said, changed consign order, but it only worked when i removed consign completely

Comment: try checking out their repo and see if its out of date/ not being maintained. unfortunately this is a problem that happens with alot of node.js repositories. i would also try reporting the bug on their github page if you are sure its not caused by your code. also consider, there could be a conflict between `consign` and another middleware library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your sample code, you don't seem to be using `consign` correctly. The included files (using `.include` or `.then` there after) should export one function which takes the express app as parameter. Check [this example](https://github.com/jarradseers/consign/blob/develop/examples/express/api/routers/user.js) in consign repo. Functions from each of the included file is called with the object which you provide to `.into()`. You can very well let go of consign, and manually require and use each fo the files, which seems to be working as per your comments.

Otherwise you can change your routes files to something like this:

server.js doesn't change.

app/routes/index.js changes to following:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'API' });
});

/* ENDPOINTS*/
/* 
  /languages -- all
  /language?idLanguage
  /language?name=
  /languages?idCategory
  /language?name=
  /categories
  //
*/

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use('/', router);
}
```

Followed by similar changes in all other files that you'd use with `consign`.